# Alternative to to C# minor to G# minor progression on ukulele?

Tags: chords, ukulele

I'm a beginner on the uke, and I'm having some trouble with a chord progression my brother wrote for a song on guitar. Essentially, the trouble I'm having boils down to a quick couple quick moves between C# minor and G# minor.

I've been using the following fingerings because I thought they would be easiest.

C# minor:

[image]

G# minor:

[image]

But, I'm still struggling. And, while I'm enjoying the challenge, I'm curious if there's another progression that I might be able to substitute or even that might sound nice as an accompaniment.

Comment: Depends on the context. But you can try E instead of C#m and B instead of Abm.

Comment: @KrisVanBael Good idea, although it's worth noting that the E chord on the ukulele often poses a threat in and of itself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the context, such as the key of the song, the rest of the chords and their functions it is difficult to suggest an effective alternative chord progression. One thing I can suggest is a different way to play the C#m, which might make it easier for you to make the switch. Try 6-4-4-4. You can barre the top 3 strings with your 1st finger and play the 6th fret of the G string with the 3rd finger. Another option suggested by @user45266 is to use 1-4-4-4. This requires more of a stretch but keeps the 1st finger in the 1st fret for both chords.

Comment: Better than 6-4-4-4 is 1-4-4-4, in my opinion. Trade-off with that voicing is that one has to stretch one fret farther, but in return gets to eliminate the position shift by staying down near the headstock. And a lot of finger repositioning gets easier during the switches, especially with the 4th finger barring the 4th fret.

Comment: @user45266 That works, I included it as an option in my answer. Since I don’t play much uke voicings like that don’t usually occur to me,